# Trace in SQL Server 2005 Mobile Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce, trace

Is there any tool available, from Microsoft or 3rd party, that allows a trace to be performed on Windows Mobile 6 device running Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Mobile Edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Mobile Edition (or, Compact Edition as it's called now) isn't really a SQL Server, only a datafile, you can not trace the same way as the other editions. You need to put debug-info in the application which utilizes the database